# Why is the Timer not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

[Note - script doesn't work in JSfiddle but works fine in chrome]
The script below ,consists of a 3second timer on the completion of which it displays the text "Time Up!".This works fine on the first try but on the next attempt it starts to mix seconds and the text "Time Up!" (gets displayed between seconds) .Why does this happen?

http://jsfiddle.net/starzar/86uqrtzs/32/

```js
function timer() {
  var t = 3;

  console.log("timer started t = " + t);


  setInterval(function() {
    if (t >= 0) {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = t;
      console.log(t);
      t--;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time Up!";
    }
  }, 1000);


  console.log("timer stopped t = " + t);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src=timer.js></script>

</head>

<body>


  <input type=Reset onclick=timer()> <br>

  <hi id="timer"></hi> <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you click **Reset button**, it creates a new interval. That's why as you click **Reset button** more, your console output gets messier.

**setInterval** function returns the id of the interval created, you can store it in a global variable like **window.timerInterval**.

Inside your timer function, run **clearInterval(window.timerInterval)** first. Therefore, if there are any intervals created and stored at **window.timerInterval**, **clearInterval(window.timerInterval)** makes sure to stop running it in the first place.

Check and run the working example below:

```js
function timer() {
  var t = 3;

  console.log("timer started t = " + t);

  clearInterval(window.timerInterval);

  window.timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (t >= 0) {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = t;
      console.log(t);
      t--;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time Up!";
    }
  }, 1000);


  console.log("timer stopped t = " + t);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src=timer.js></script>

</head>

<body>


  <input type=Reset onclick=timer()> <br>

  <hi id="timer"></hi> <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to clear it using `clearInterval()...`!

Look at this code as a reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_clearinterval

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When starting an interval it will last forever if you don't clear it.

Your first interval that was started on the first call is still running in the background. You can clearly see it in the below example.

You should use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

```js
function timer() {
  var t = 3;

  console.log("timer started t = " + t);


  setInterval(function() {
    if (t >= 0) {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = t;
      console.log(t);
      t--;
    } else {
      console.log("Time up");
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time Up!";
    }
  }, 1000);


  console.log("timer stopped t = " + t);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src=timer.js></script>

</head>

<body>


  <input type=Reset onclick=timer()> <br>

  <hi id="timer"></hi> <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

SetInterval performs an action repeatedly in the specified interval.

In your case you should use setTimeOut.

```
 var timerConst; 
 function timer() {

 if(timerConst) clearTimeOut( timerConst); // this will clear the previous timeout.

  timerConst = setTimeOut(function() {
    console.log("Time up");
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time Up!";
   }, 3000);}
```

This will display a text after 3 seconds.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp